# invertible function

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

for bijective function $f:U \to V$ , $f \in C^1$ $J_{D_{f}} \neq 0$ for any $ x\in U$ $, U\in \Bbb{R}^n, V\in \Bbb{R}^n $ open sets.
I tried to show that $f^{-1} \in C^1$.
I know the Inverse Function Theorem (locally) but how can I conclude it for global $f^{-1}:V \to U$
thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to realize is that differentiability and continuity are local properties: A map $g \colon V \to U$ is differentiable/continuous on $V$ if and only if for every $y \in V$ there exists an open neighborhood $V_y \subseteq V$ of $y$ such that $g$ is differentiable/continuous on $V_y$. This follows directly from the fact that both the derivative $Dg(y)$ as well as the continuity of $g$ at $y$ are defined in terms of limits, which only depend upon a arbitrarily small open neighborhood of $y$.

For every $y \in V$ there exists by the Inverse Function Theorem an open neighborhood $V_y \subseteq V$ of $y$ and an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x = f^{-1}(y)$ such that $f^{-1}(V_y) = U_x$ and $f^{-1}|_{V_y} \colon V_y \to U_x$ is continuously differentiable, i.e. $f^{-1}|_{V_y}$ is differentiable on $V_y$ and $D(f^{-1}|_{V_y})$ is continuous on $V_y$.

Because $V = \bigcup_{y \in V} V_y$ and differentiability is a local property we find that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable on $V$. For every $y \in V$ we have $Df^{-1}(y) = D(f^{-1}|_{V_y})(y)$, so $Df^{-1}(y)$ is continuous on a neighborhood of $y$. Again from $V = \bigcup_{y \in V} V_y$ it follows that $Df^{-1}$ is already continous on $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $J_{D_f} \not=0$ for any $x$ then The Inverse Function Theorem gives us that the derivative of the inverse is the inverse of the derivative. So if $J_{D_f}$ varies continuously then $J_{D_{f^{-1}}}$ must also vary continuously.